# Understanding matrix with greater than or equal

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I'm reading a book and it states the following:

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        v\\
        u\\
        \end{bmatrix} \ge k
$$

Does this mean that BOTH v and u are greater than or equal to k? If not, could someone please clarify.

Comment: Are you sure it was not $v\choose u$, the binomial coefficient?

Comment: If you are referring to rounded brackets, then no, it is definitely square brackets.

Comment: If it is not a binomial, it still must be some function of $v$ and $u$ to give a single number.  I suggest you look back in the book for what the symbol means, or maybe there is a list of symbols.

Comment: To answer this question, it is necessary to know, what kind of object is described by this notation exactly and in what context the inequality is written down.

Comment: v is the number of rows of a matrix that we _want_ to build and u is the number of zeros per column.

Comment: You should probably give a proper reference of your source.

Comment: The bracket notation can have multiple signification. For exemple, I've seen it denote the unsigned Stirling number of the first kind (but it can be something else)

Comment: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ics3hy1t7d9b96u/Gertler%20%282000%29%20-%20Structure%20Parity%20Equations%20in%20Fault%20Detection%20and%20Isolation.pdf?dl=0) Page 8 of this document. I'm really lost with this.

Comment: Vector inequalities (like that) are common in linear programming/optimization--in that case the k is always a vector.  If k happens to be a vector then it would mean component-wise inequality.  If k is a scalar... and the left hand side is indeed a vector, then it must mean that both components are at least k.

Comment: After looking at the reference (briefly), I don't think it makes sense that the left hand side is a vector.  It is probably some notation for either a binomial coefficient (square brackets are used for those in some texts) or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the reference you gave, I don’t think it is completely clear, what this notation means. $v ≥ 0 ∧ μ ≥ 0$ could make sense, but I can’t be sure without a detailed understanding of the subject-matter. You should look into other work of Gertler (e.g. follow the references given) and see where he explains the condition more thoroughly.